# overflow:auto when textarea has content by default?

Tags: css, textarea, overflow

This is a problem, that has annoyed me for a long time. If I have a textarea with long text in it, overflow doesn't work, even if content goes over the visible area. How to fix this?

Martti Laine

Comment: Do you mean horizontal overflow? Vertical overflow? Which overflow behaviour do you see, which one would you prefer (hidden/visible/scroll/auto)?

Comment: Horizontal is the goal. It is set at scroll/auto, but contents of the textarea are still wrapped. If I write manually something to textarea, it doesn't wrap.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the comments:

> Horizontal is the goal. It is set at scroll/auto, but contents of the textarea are still wrapped. If I write manually something to textarea, it doesn't wrap.

So you basically want to disable the wrapping of lines? Add `white-space: nowrap;` to the style. This has another impact however: you cannot display nor insert newlines in the textarea anymore.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a height set on your area?  (Also, I am assuming this not a `<textarea>` but a `<div>` or something like that).

Answer (score 0):

So, you want the text to wrap when you manually enter text? If you are using a `<textarea>` control, you might try setting the height and width:

```
<textarea id="test" style="width:300px; height:50px">
    The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
</textarea>
```